# How do I switch it to Hardcore Mode in SMP?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My friends and I want to see if we can set a Minecraft Server to Hardcore mode. What number do you need to set the `difficulty` option to for Hardcore? e.g. Peaceful = 1, Normal = 2, etc.

Answer (score 4):

[According to the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server.properties#Minecraft_server_properties), there's no option for it on servers. Hardcore isn't a difficulty, it's a separate gamemode, and the only options for that is creative and survival.

This kind of makes sense too. Since the world is deleted when the player dies, it'd be harder to handle it when there are multiple players, waiting until they're all dead. Also, no one could drop in, and what if all the players just disconnected, and someone else joined while they were gone and died?

Comment: Perhaps a simple way to *simulate* hardcore would be to IP ban players when they die.

Comment: yeah, i've seen server like that before

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate the responses. Although my friends are disappointed, im glad. I am freaking terrified of creepers! :) Thank you again!

Comment: Can you guys tell me what the Hard difficulty number is? I'm just lost. Also, Ullallulloo, why did you edit my question? It doesnt have voice now xD. But why?

Comment: @MCRmy139: Hard = 4. Sorry, I thought it sounded more professional. If you don't like it, you can change it back.

Comment: Just a bump: this is out of date and not accurate anymore!

Answer (score 3):

In Minecraft 1.3.1 and later, you can simply edit your `server.properties` files.

Locate the line that says `hardcore=false` and change the `false` to `true`. Voilà!

Answer (score 2):

If you use Bukkit 1.8.1, you can use this pretty plugin: [Hardcore](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/hardcore/)

It's not updated to 1.0.0 yet , but it probably will after RB of Bukkit get released.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not allowed to get Bukkit, my parents wont allow me, and even if i tried, my parents would either delete the files, tell my parents, or both :/ Thank you though!

Comment: @MCRmy139 Why in the world would your parents not allow you to use Bukkit?  All it is-is a modified version of the normal server.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN change your server to hardcore and without a plugin. I just don't know how I did it. I had a bukkit server and when I updated to 1.3.1 the server changed to hardcore. When you die it says "You died in hardcore. It's game over man!" The only way to pardon them is to get their IP address and type in `/pardon-ip <ip address>`.

Comment: This doesn't actually say how to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Create a map in single player and set the game type to hard core once its created move it into your bukkit install and set it up as your default map in your server properties.

Comment: Are you sure this will work? I'm pretty certain this does nothing but making you kaeep that world, not the hardcore setting.

Comment: This doesn't actually work. The server.properties overrides the settings in level.dat.

Answer (score -3):

Create one on singleplayer and put it as the default world and voila, it's hardcore. 
This works. I tried it myself.

Comment: This does NOT work at all. moving over a world does exactly nothing. You have to set hardcore in the server config or possibly via some command(if that's even possible).